# Creating custom blocks using EV3 block developer kit

Tags: programming, ev3-g

I am trying to develop a custom block using ev3 block development kit but I get nowhere. I created the XML files according to the documentation and the VIX file but it does not compile, I cannot export it to a ev3b file and so on.

Can anyone give me some direction (documentation, procedure, hits - anything) in order to proceed.